# What's the difference between R6RS's `letrec`, `letrec*` and Racket's `letrec`?

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs, letrec

Both `letrec` and `letrec*` are in R6RS, but there's [only](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._letrec%29%29) `letrec` in Racket, no `letrec*`. What are the differences between these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short Racket `letrec` and R6RS `letrec*` is the same.
The evaluation order is specified for these.
In R5RS `letrec` the order is unspecified.

Since the order of R5RS `letrec` is unspecified implementation can choose
a fixed order (for example left to right) or they can let the compiler
choose different orders for each use (in order to get faster code).

From the Racket documentation.

[R5RS letrec](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html?q=letrec#%25_idx_134):

> Semantics: The < variable>s are bound to fresh locations holding
>   undefined values, the < init>s are evaluated in the resulting
>   environment (in some unspecified order), each < variable> is assigned
>   to the result of the corresponding < init>, the < body> is evaluated in
>   the resulting environment, and the value(s) of the last expression in
>   < body> is(are) returned. Each binding of a < variable> has the entire
>   letrec expression as its region, making it possible to define mutually
>   recursive procedures.

[Racket letrec](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=letrec#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._letrec%29%29):

> Like let, including left-to-right evaluation of the val-exprs, but the
>   locations for all ids are created first and filled with #< undefined>,
>   all ids are bound in all val-exprs as well as the bodys, and each id
>   is set immediately after the corresponding val-expr is evaluated. The
>   ids must be distinct according to bound-identifier=?.

[R6RS `letrec*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs-std/r6rs-Z-H-14.html?q=letrec#node_idx_406):

> Semantics: The < variable>s are bound to fresh locations, each
>   < variable> is assigned in left-to-right order to the result of
>   evaluating the corresponding < init>, the < body> is evaluated in the
>   resulting environment, and the values of the last expression in < body>
>   are returned. Despite the left-to-right evaluation and assignment
>   order, each binding of a < variable> has the entire letrec* expression
>   as its region, making it possible to define mutually recursive
>   procedures.

Comment: For completeness, you might care to add the R7RS semantics as R7RS is official now.

Comment: As far as I can tell there have been no changes in the meaning of letrec and letrec* in R7RS. That is, letrec in R7RS have the same meaning as in R5RS and R6RS. In R7RS letrec* has the same meaning as it did in R6RS.